# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable....in tensorflow V.2.1.0

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to write this tensorflow tutorial and I got the below error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0',
>   'Variable_1:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable_1:0', 'Variable:0',
>   'Variable_1:0', 'Variable_6:0', 'Variable_7:0'].

```
import tensorflow as tf
# from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
# mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder('float')

class NN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hidden_1_layer = {}
        self.hidden_2_layer = {} 
        self.hidden_3_layer = {} 
        self.output_layer = {}
    def neural_network_model(self,data):

        self.hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

        self.hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

        self.hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

        self.output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.compat.v1.random.normal([n_classes])),}


        l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,self.hidden_1_layer['weights']), self.hidden_1_layer['biases'])
        l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

        l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,self.hidden_2_layer['weights']), self.hidden_2_layer['biases'])
        l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

        l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,self.hidden_3_layer['weights']), self.hidden_3_layer['biases'])
        l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

        output = tf.matmul(l3,self.output_layer['weights']) + self.output_layer['biases']

        return output

    def train_neural_network(self,x):
        prediction = self.neural_network_model(x)
        cost = lambda: tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y) )
        optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam().minimize(cost, var_list=[self.hidden_1_layer['weights'],self.hidden_1_layer['biases'],self.hidden_2_layer['weights'],self.hidden_2_layer['biases'],self.hidden_3_layer['weights'],self.hidden_3_layer['biases'],self.output_layer['weights'],self.output_layer['biases']])

        hm_epochs = 10
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
                epoch_loss = 0
                for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                    epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                    epoch_loss += c

                print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

            correct = tf.math.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
            print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))


model = NN()
model.train_neural_network(x)
```

tensorflow version is 2.1.0..
[edit]: to initilize layers in **init**
where is the problem?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you are mixing TF 2.x optimizers with TF 1.x sessions etc. I suggest you check the [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials) for more up-to-date tutorials for the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... If your new to tensorflow, you should really become familiar with layers, training, testing, making models, and such. From what I can tell, what you have above is a detailed expansion of what goes on under the hood of the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data() 
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([  
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500,'relu'),  
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500,'relu'),  
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500,'relu'),  
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,'softmax'),  
]) 
model.compile('adam','sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(*mnist[0],validation_data=mnist[1],epochs=1,batch_size=128)
#Trains in 1 min or less on cpu. Few seconds on gpu. 

#Plot some data to see what you trained. 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(mnist[0][0][0]) 
plt.show()
#Does this look like a 5? 

#Here are first few predictions for the images. 
model.predict(mnist[0][0][0:5]).round().argmax(1) 
#Notice the first image was predicted to be a 5 by the trained model. 

#Here is what we trained to predict. 
mnist[0][1][0:5]
#Do our labels match what our model predicts? 

#Accuracy (match the predicted against our labels)
matching = model.predict(mnist[1][0]).round().argmax(1) == mnist[1][1]
print(sum(matching)/len(matching)*100)
```

I got an accuracy of 93.95%. Play with the layers, change 'relu' to 'sigmoid', change the 500 neurons to 400. Try 'sgd' instead of 'adam'. Do more epochs. Increase the batch_size to 1000. What trains faster? What trains slower? Can you get an accuracy of 95%, 98%, 99.9%? Hope this helps.